# attempt to apply non-function when using roxygenise(), can't find source of error

Tags: rcpp, roxygen

I'm trying to use add documentation to my arbitrary Rcpp package using roxygen2, and I keep getting the same error message

```
> roxygen2::roxygenise("anRpackage")
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function
In addition: Warning message:
roxygen2 requires Encoding: UTF-8
```

I do not have ".f(.x[[i]])" anywhere in my source code, and I don't recognize the form ".f". Is this some kind of hidden function? How should I debug this error? I'm quite new to writing R packages, perhaps I'm missing something.... Thanks in advance!

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(roxygen2)
sessionInfo()
```

The output is the following:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] roxygen2_6.1.0            RcppArmadillo_0.9.100.5.0 Rcpp_0.12.18             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 R6_2.2.2       magrittr_1.5   tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.14   
[6] xml2_1.1.1     stringi_1.1.6  stringr_1.2.0  commonmark_1.4
```

Comment: Can you by chance share the repository or provide a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have quite a lot of code in my package, but this error seems persistent with every function I write. I later created a brand new package with the skeleton function, which creates a default rcpparma_hello_world.cpp file with some example code. And i still got the exact same error. This is quite confusing and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here is the exact code I used: `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("anRpackage"); compileAttributes("anRpackage");roxygen2::roxygenise("anRpackage")

Comment: Your commands work when used with an Rcpp skeleton instead of one from RcppArmadillo. However, that does not do anything sensible, since those skeletons do not contain any roxygen comments. Do you want to use roxygen for documentation, NAMESPACE or both?

Comment: I just tried your sequence of commands: `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton();  Rcpp::compileAttributes("anRpackage"); roxygen2::roxygenise("anRpackage");`. No error messages here.

Comment: Like [Ralf Stubner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416610/ralf-stubner), I also ran that sequence of commands and did not get any error messages. Can you run the following commands and edit your question to include the output? `library(Rcpp); library(RcppArmadillo); library(roxygen2); sessionInfo()`

Comment: @duckmayr I'm still getting the same errors. What sort of results from sessionInfo() are you looking for? My R version is 3.4.2, is that where the issue it?

Comment: @lollipop R version, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, and roxygen2 versions, OS type....

Comment: @lollipop just include the full output of `sessionInfo()`. That would be really helpful ...

Comment: @lollipop: And when you then please _edit the question_ rather than pile it in here under comments which are far less readable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but I want to record my failed attempt at reproducing the issue. Since I am using a more current version of R and have no windows environment available, I am using a docker container with your R version. Preperations

```
$ docker run --rm -it rocker/r-ver:3.4.2 bash
# apt-get update
# apt-get install libxml2-dev
# install2.r -r https://cloud.r-project.org/ RcppArmadillo roxygen2
```

Session info:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> library(RcppArmadillo)
> library(roxygen2)
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C             
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] roxygen2_6.1.0            RcppArmadillo_0.9.100.5.0
[3] Rcpp_0.12.18             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 R6_2.2.2       magrittr_1.5   tools_3.4.2    xml2_1.2.0    
[6] stringi_1.1.6  stringr_1.2.0  commonmark_1.5
```

Your commands:

```
> RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("anRpackage"); compileAttributes("anRpackage");roxygen2::roxygenise("anRpackage") 

Calling package.skeleton to create basic package.
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './anRpackage/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding RcppArmadillo settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
 >> added useDynLib and importFrom directives to NAMESPACE
 >> added Makevars file with Rcpp settings
 >> added Makevars.win file with RcppArmadillo settings
 >> added example src file using armadillo classes
 >> added example Rd file for using armadillo classes
 >> invoked Rcpp::compileAttributes to create wrappers
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Updating roxygen version in /anRpackage/DESCRIPTION
Loading anRpackage
Re-compiling anRpackage
Running /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL /anRpackage \
  '--library=/tmp/RtmpbM1VEb/devtools_install_7e040f6ccc8' --no-R --no-data \
  --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch \
  --no-test-load --preclean
* installing *source* package ‘anRpackage’ ...
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -Og -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp  -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -Og -fdiagnostics-color=always -c rcpparma_hello_world.cpp -o rcpparma_hello_world.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o anRpackage.so RcppExports.o rcpparma_hello_world.o -fopenmp -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lRlapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /tmp/RtmpbM1VEb/devtools_install_7e040f6ccc8/anRpackage/libs
* DONE (anRpackage)
Warning: The existing 'NAMESPACE' file was not generated by roxygen2, and will not be overwritten.
Warning message:
roxygen2 requires Encoding: UTF-8
```

The only differences I am seeing are the OS and some not attached packages that are slightly newer in my docker container. Nothing that would explain the failure on your side.

Comment: Nicely done.  As aside, in more recent R binary packages for Debian (and Ubuntu) I now also set the default CRAN mirror (to the same CDN) so you no longer need the `-r` switch.  And `.deb` binaries are of course also available for RcppArmadillo and roxygen2.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Indeed, if I had used `rocker/r-base:3.4.2` instead of `rocker/r-ver:3.4.2` it would have been even simpler.

Comment: Bingo. That is Carl building from source for the versioned stack so it lacks some of these in-the-package customizations.  So what I said was actually not correct for the container you used.  My bad.

Comment: Hey guys, I updated my R to the latest version and re-run the commands, and everything worked smoothly, no errors. I still don't understand why it didn't work before though..... Thanks so much for all your help