# Error while documenting R package using Roxygen2

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, roxygen

I am trying to create a documentation for my R package using roxygen2, however, when I click to document, I get the following error:

```
First time using roxygen2. Upgrading automatically...
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply a non-function
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... read_pkg_description -> 
read.description -> <Anonymous> -> .Call -> .f
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? I've seen this a few times with older R versions where the error went away once they upgraded R to a more recent version (see, for example, comments on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065068/attempt-to-apply-non-function-when-using-roxygenise-cant-find-source-of-erro))

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code which, in this case, is likely a barebones skeleton package. If you have a public github/gitlab repo with the problem, please provide it. Otherwise, please create a small skeleton package and slowly bring in each file (starting with `zzz.R`, if it exists) until the error manifests. Laborious, yes. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.